# Why during davening do we ask Hashem to answer us on the day we call, don't we always call?

Tags: tefilla

In davening we say numerous times ה' הושִׁיעָה. הַמֶּלֶךְ יַעֲנֵנוּ בְיום קָרְאֵנוּ, which translates as "Hashem deliver us, the king will answer us on the day we call".

Why does it say we request from God to answer us on the day we call - aren't we always calling for Hashem to answer us? Why doesn't it say we ask God to answer us while we call him?

Can anyone explain this to me, bring sources or just provide reason.

Comment: Would you rather he answer the day after you call?

Comment: Isn't this more of a question on Tehillim where the verse appears than the prayer service?

Comment: I guess so, but we say it in davening more than in Tehillim

Comment: @Josh Depends how often you say Tehillim.

Comment: @magicker72 that is correct

Comment: "why doesn't it say we ask God to answer us while we call him." - Something to consider, perhaps, since you mention davening - There another verse that we mention on fast days as part of *Aneinu* (I think the verse comes from Yirmiyahu or Yeshayahu) that requests that G-d answer us **before** we call him. Hmmm ... is that a contradiction?? Suggestion - clarify this question. I may follow up with mine as a separate question built upon yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This verse, which is part of our daily prayers comes from Psalm 20 verse 10. It is said in several places throughout our prayers. (If you include the full recitation of Psalm 20, which is occasionally omitted, I think we say this verse 4 times on a weekday.)

You need to understand the context of this verse with its relation to verses 8 and 9. Summarizing [Radak's](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=74) explanation on verse 10 (vesre you cited), it refers to those people who yell (pray) to G-d for assistance during the time of war. Verse 8 says that other nations rely on the might of their horses and chariots, but we will proclaim the name of G-d (i.e. - we rely on G-d to help or save us during war.) Thus, we ask that G-d save us when we call to him - during war.